# Cannot connect to kafka connect cluster running on AWS from outside EC2

Tags: apache-kafka, amazon-ecs, apache-kafka-connect

I have an ECS cluster with 3 EC2 instances all sitting in private subnets. I created a task definition to run the kafka-connect image provided by Confluent with the following environment variables:

```
    CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=quickstart-config
    CONNECT_GROUP_ID=quickstart
    CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=quickstart-offsets
    CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/share/java
    CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=localhost
    CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_PORT=8083
    CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL=SSL
    CONNECT_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM=
    CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=quickstart-status
    CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
```

I have an application load balancer in front of this cluster with a listener on port 8083. I have correctly set up target group to include the EC2 instances running kafka-connect. So the load balancer should forward requests to the cluster. And it does, but I always get back a `502 Bad Gateway` response. I can ssh into the EC2 instances and `curl localhost:8083` and get the response back from kafka-connect, but from outside the EC2, I don't get a response.

To rule out networking issues between the load balancer and the cluster, I created a separate task defintion running Nginx on port 80 and I'm able to successfully hit it from outside the EC2 instances through the load balancer.

I have a feeling that I have not set `CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` to the correct value. It's my understanding that this is the host clients should connect to. However, because my EC2 instances are in a private subnet, I have no idea what to set this to, which is why I've set it to localhost. I tried setting it to the load balancer's DNS name, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set `CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` to the host or IP that *the other Kafka Connect workers can resolve and connect to*.

It's used for the internal communication between workers, and if it's `localhost` then if your REST request (via your load balancer) hits a worker that is not the current leader of the cluster, that worker will try to forward the request to the leader—using the `CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME`. But if `CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` is `localhost` then the worker will simply be forwarding the request *to itself* and hence things won't work.

For more details see https://rmoff.net/2019/11/22/common-mistakes-made-when-configuring-multiple-kafka-connect-workers/

Comment: Thank you for your insight. My only question is if I only have 1 EC2 instance in my cluster (since posting this question I've scaled down from 3 EC2 instances to 1 for debugging reasons), and I keep `CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` set to `localhost`, shouldn't this work? I'm still getting 502 Bad Gateway errors when trying to connect from outside the EC2 instance.

Comment: Yes, but if you only have one worker do you need the load balancer?

Comment: any updates? did you managed to find a solution?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt if I want a 3 node cluster - should each instance have a different CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME? 
for example - connect-node-1, connect-node-2, connect-node-3 ?

Comment: I'm running on ECS, adding the following to a script that runs at the start of the container seems to fix it: 
```TASK=$(hostname -i)
CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=$TASK /etc/confluent/docker/run```

It's based on https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-ecs-fargate-workshop-dev-ops-data/blob/master/labs/stream-processing-pipelines/s3sink/set_env.sh I used `hostname -i` because I was not able to install jq on the server